# Change css content color with javascript

Tags: jquery, css

I'm trying to change this spans color with javascript when some event occurs

```
.line-numbers-rows > span:before {
  content: counter(linenumber);
  color: #999;
  display: block;
  padding-right: 0.8em;
  text-align: right;
}

var child = angular.element(children[i]);
child.css( { backgroundColor: 'rgba( +' + split[0] + ',' + split[1] + ',' + split[2] + ',0.5)' } );
child.css( {color: 'rgba(39,40,34,1)'} );
console.log(child);
```

The background color changes, but the content color doesn't. And if i check the console.log() i can see that both styles were applied to the element.

Comment: try `child.css( {color: 'rgba(39,40,34,1)!important'} );`

Comment: Try using $scope.$apply() after performing the DOM manipulation.

Comment: `child.css( { cssText: 'color:rgba(39,40,34,1) !important;' } )` did not work

Comment: i don't think scope.apply is needed as the background-color changes

Comment: If you are using angular you don't need to do that type of manipulation, just put both styles in an ng-class or an ng-style